# client side validation in mvc3 for dependent fields

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, client, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

Hi
I have an MVC3 appliocation and using client side validation and find it to be very usefull.
I am having 2 issues while using it.
-One is there any possiblity of Required filed dependency as it there for Compare
eg: If the value of a particular filed say status is="Test" then the value of other say status done field must be not blank otherwise it can be blank.
- I am having a dropdown say state .If its value is "Other" then need to make a textbox visible say "other state" .For know I am using javasript to make it visible.
I donot want to use javasript for that. Can this be performed without using javascript.

Comment: you just said 'I dont want to use javascript for that' and then 'can this be done with javascript' - thats a bit confusing.

Comment: Similar question here - [mvc3 validate input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736710/mvc3-validate-input-not-equal-to/5742164#5742164)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own custom compare attribute or simply use javascript. Nothing is built in that will do this for you. The other option is to provide server side validation in your controller method where you check this situation and if it fails use ModelState.AddError to give a custom validation error.