# MVC3 Validate input not-equal attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have implemented the NotEqual attribute exactly as provided by Darin Dimitrov at:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5742494/1946707

The problem I am getting here is I am using a jQuery dialog, and want to get validations on the client side on my dialog. My required validations fire, but the validations for not equal do not work on the client side... any help would be appreciated.

Here is my model:

```
public class ChangePasswordModel
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Current password")]
    public string OldPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [NotEqual("OldPassword", ErrorMessage = "should be different than Prop1")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "New password")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm new password")]
    [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ChangePassword", "Account", new { area = "" }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "changePasswordForm" }))
{

    <a href="#" onclick="openChangePasswordDialog();">Change Password</a>
    <div id="dialogChangePassword" title="Change Password">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.OldPassword)
                </td>
                <td>@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.OldPassword)
                </td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.OldPassword)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.NewPassword)
                </td>
                <td>@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.NewPassword)
                </td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.NewPassword)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                </td>
                <td>@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                </td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

Here is my javascript:

```
    var changePasswordDialogId = '#dialogChangePassword';
    var oldPasswordInput = '#changePasswordForm #OldPassword';
    var newPasswordInput = '#changePasswordForm #NewPassword';
    var confirmPasswordInput = '#changePasswordForm #ConfirmPassword';

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(changePasswordDialogId).dialog(
    {
        autoOpen: false,
        autoResize: true,
        modal: true,
        open: function () {
            $(this).parent().appendTo("#changePasswordForm");
        },
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                if ($(oldPasswordInput).valid() && $(newPasswordInput).valid() && $(confirmPasswordInput).valid()) {
                    alert('ready to post!');
                    $(changePasswordDialogId).dialog('close');
                }
            },
            Cancel: function () {
                $(changePasswordDialogId).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
});       //document.ready

function openChangePasswordDialog() {
    $(changePasswordDialogId).dialog('open');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found my issue. I had missed the inheritance from `IClientValidatable` 
Now that I have added it, it works on the client side, even in my jQuery dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you forgot to register your validation adapter

```
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
        'notequalto', ['other'], function (options) {
            options.rules['notEqualTo'] = '#' + options.params.other;
            if (options.message) {
                options.messages['notEqualTo'] = options.message;
            }
    });
```

Which Darin Dimitrov specified in his answer.

Comment: I have that added in a separate javascript file, and I am including the file in my head section of the view.