# Create AddValidation Method for Custom Attribute Inheriting IClientModelValidator

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-core

I'm implementing a custom attribute to ensure two form values are not equal.
There is a solution similar that doesn't quite work for ASP.NET Core here
[mvc3 validate input 'not-equal-to'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5736710/mvc3-validate-input-not-equal-to)

```
 public class NotEqualAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
    {

            public string OtherProperty { get; private set; }
            public NotEqualAttribute(string otherProperty)
            {
                OtherProperty = otherProperty;
            }

            protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
            {
                var property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(OtherProperty);
                if (property == null)
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(
                        string.Format(
                            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                            "{0} is unknown property",
                            OtherProperty
                        )
                    );
                }
                var otherValue = property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);
                if (object.Equals(value, otherValue))
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
                }
                return null;
            }


        }
}
```

How do I implement the `IClientValidator` `AddValidation()` method to use the following jQuery? I've verified that the attribute works correctly on the server side

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
        'notequalto', ['other'], function (options) {
            options.rules['notEqualTo'] = '#' + options.params.other;
            if (options.message) {
                options.messages['notEqualTo'] = options.message;
            }
    });

    jQuery.validator.addMethod('notEqualTo', function(value, element, param) {
        return this.optional(element) || value != $(param).val();
    }, '');
</script>
```

EDIT:
I was able to get a workaround by instead having the `NotEqualAttribute` class inherit from the `CompareAttribute'. This allowed me to do away with the jQuery piece. However, if anyone can lead me to how to use the unobstrusive jQuery validation as an alternative, I would be interested

```
public class NotEqualAttribute : CompareAttribute
    {
        public string BasePropertyName { get; private set; }
        private const string DefaultErrorMessage = "'{0}' and '{1}' must not be the same.";
        public NotEqualAttribute(string otherProperty)
        : base(otherProperty)
    {
            BasePropertyName = otherProperty;
        }

        public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
        {
            return string.Format(DefaultErrorMessage, name, BasePropertyName);
        }
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var result = base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
            if (result == null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```